# Find and write certain words in lines to a file in python

Tags: python, regex, file, text, nltk

I have a .txt file in cyrillic. It's structure is like that but in cyrillic:

```
city text text text.#1#N
river, text text.#3#Name (Name1, Name2, Name3)   
lake text text text.#5#N (Name1)        
mountain text text.#23#Na
```

What I need:
   1) look at the first word in a line
   2) if it is "river" then write all words after "**#3#**", i.e. Name (Name1, Name2, Name3) in a file 'river'.

That I have to do also with another first words in lines, i. e. **city, lake, mountain**.
What I have done only finds if the first word is "city" and saves whole line to a file:

```
lines = f.readlines()
for line in lines:
    if line.startswith('city'):
        f2.write(line)
f.close()
f2.close()
```

I know I can use regex to find Names: #[0-9]+#(\W+) but I don't know how to implement it to a code.
I really need your help! And I'm glad for any help.

Comment: I have edited my post to make it clearerю

Comment: hi! you can try your regexes with debuggex.com! they have a python setting

Answer (score 0):

If all of your river**s have ,s after them, like in the above code you posted, I would do something like:

```
for line in f.readlines():
     items = line.split("**,")
     if items[0] == "**river":
          names = line.split("#")[1].strip().split("(")[1].split(")")[0].split(",")
          names = [Name1, Name2, Name3]
          #.. now write each one
```

Comment: Thnx for answering. I have edited my post so that there are no river**s and Name is changeble. What can I do with this? Thnx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do here is avoid hard-coding the names of the files you need. Instead, glean that from the input file. Create a dictionary of the files you need to writing to, opening each one as it's needed. Something like this (untested and probably in need of some adaptation):

```
 outfiles = {}
 try:
     with open("infile.txt") as infile:
         for line in infile:
             tag = line.split(" ", 1)[0].strip("*, ")     # e.g. "river"
             if tag not in outfiles:   # if it's the first time we've seen a tag
                 outfiles[tag] = open(tag = ".txt", "w")  # open tag.txt to write
             content = line.rsplit("#", 1)[-1].strip("* ")
             outfiles[tag].write(content + "\n")
 finally:
     for outfile in outfiles.itervalues():
         outfile.close()
```

Comment: I'd adapt slightly to use: `outfiles.setdefault(tag, open('tag' + '.txt', 'w')).write(content + '\n')` instead of checking

Comment: That's going to open the file again *every time* it hits `setdefault()` since `open()` will be evaluated before being passed in. You could subclass `dict` and override `__missing__` though!

Comment: good point. Not quite sure why that seemed such a good idea when it's a terrible suggestion :)... Oh well - we're entitled to a brain burp now and again! It's just a shame it appears to work...